# Dask Future has state "cancelled" without having been cancelled

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed, concurrent.futures, dask-ssh

Im am building a dask application and using the Dask SSH-Cluster as a Cluster. When I run a task in Dask and try to await it, it causes a `concurrent.futures._base.CancelledError` Error.

My Code is the following:

```py
def run_custom_task():
    return "aa"


def main():
    cluster = SSHCluster(hosts=['localhost', 'pi01.local'],
                         connect_options=[{'username': 'abc'}, {'username': 'pi'}],
                         worker_options={
                             "nprocs": 1,
                             "nthreads": 1
                         }, 
                         remote_python="/usr/bin/python3")
    client = Client(cluster)

    res = client.submit(run_custom_task)
    print(res.result())
```

The exact error I receive is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 65, in <module>
    main()
  File "test.py", line 59, in main
    x = res.result()
  File "/home/rohan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/client.py", line 222, in result
    raise result
concurrent.futures._base.CancelledError: run_custom_task-966de894af6e709f1e8067f6e9ffe68
```

so it seems that the future for this task is being cancelled somehow.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I actually managed to solve this problem already:
The problem was that the dask.distributed and dask version were different (2021.04.0 and 2021.05.0) after installing the same version this error was solved.

Comment: Did work for me at 2022.02.0 parity